# No installed components were detected. Element is already the child of another element. UWP Error while loading a SearchBox

Tags: xaml, uwp, winrt-xaml, uwp-xaml, windows-10-universal

I am getting this **intermittent** error while loading a SearchBox and not sure what I am doing wrong here. Project has been migrated from Windows 8.1 app platform to UWP.

> No installed components were detected. Element is already the child of
> another element.

I am getting this error in App.g.i.cs. Exception is not been thrown in any of the CS files.
[image]
Here is the code. There are two SearchBox elements in the page and I am wondering if that might be the issue.

```
                <TextBlock 
                    Visibility="{
                        Binding ServiceReview.ServiceReviewType_Id,
                        Converter={StaticResource ConsumerTypeToVisibleConverter},
                        Mode=OneWay
                    }"
                    Style="{StaticResource FormTextBlock}"
                    Text="Individual's Name"/>
                <SearchBox 
                    Visibility="{
                        Binding ServiceReview.ServiceReviewType_Id,
                        Converter={StaticResource ConsumerTypeToVisibleConverter},
                        Mode=OneWay
                    }"
                    x:Name="IndividualSearchBox"
                    Style="{StaticResource FormSearchBox}"
                    PlaceholderText="Search by Individual's Name"
                    SuggestionsRequested="IndividualSearchBox_OnSuggestionsRequested"
                    ResultSuggestionChosen="IndividualSearchBox_OnResultSuggestionChosen"
                    SearchHistoryEnabled="False">
                </SearchBox>
 
                    <TextBlock
                                Style="{StaticResource FormTextBlock}"
                                Text="Search Team Members To Add"/>
                    <SearchBox
                                x:Name="UserSearchBox"
                                Style="{StaticResource FormSearchBox}"
                                PlaceholderText="Search by Team Member's Name"
                                SuggestionsRequested="UserSearchBox_OnSuggestionsRequested"
                                ResultSuggestionChosen="UserSearchBox_OnResultSuggestionChosen"
                        SearchHistoryEnabled="False">
                    </SearchBox>
```

And the UserSearchBox is giving the error.

We are loading the data like this:

```
 private async void UserSearchBox_OnSuggestionsRequested(SearchBox sender, SearchBoxSuggestionsRequestedEventArgs args)
    {
        try
        {

       
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(args.QueryText))
        {
            return;
        }

        var collection = args.Request.SearchSuggestionCollection;

        if (_oldUserQuery == args.QueryText) return;

        var deferral = args.Request.GetDeferral();

        List<Employee> employees = await _employeeService.SearchEmployees(args.QueryText);

        foreach (var employee in employees)
        {
            collection.AppendResultSuggestion(employee.FullName, string.Empty, employee.EmployeeId.ToString(), RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(
                new Uri("http://www.dotnettoscana.org/logo.png")), string.Empty);
        }

        deferral.Complete();

        _oldUserQuery = args.QueryText;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)            {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

and here is the styles associated with the control.

```
<Style TargetType="SearchBox" x:Key="FormSearchBox">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="55"/>
        <!--<Setter Property="SearchHistoryEnabled" Value="False"/>-->
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="20,0,0,15"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="380" />
        <!--Testing by moving below contents from SearchBox-->
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{StaticResource MediumThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource BorderBrushColor}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource BorderThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource AppFontSize}"/>
    </Style>
```

Any pointers towards finding the issue will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I tried your XAML code in a blank UWP project. It looks like there are some values missing like `MediumThickness`. So I removed these unknown values in the Style and the test project is running correctly.  Have you tried to run your code in a blank project to check this issue?

Comment: I haven't yet. It's an intermittent issue (Just edited and added that. How did you add the data to List of employees? I am more leaning towards this is a data related issue.

Comment: For test purposes, I just made a simple employee class. I also tried to remove all the employee logic which also shows no exception. Based on the error message, this error should happen in the XAML part.

Comment: You could also share the Employee class so that I could make a test again.